# Formation a custom widget value to look like custom date

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a custom widget, and I want to format the value as Date.

The widget value from database(is a DateField) is the following format:

`2018-04-10` and I want to be shown to user like this: `Tue Apr 03 2018`

I tried using a template filter:

```
{% if widget.value != None %} value="{{ widget.value|date:'M d, Y'}}"{% endif %}
```

but the field value gets empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass date to the template, you do not need to convert it to any format

> is the following format: 2018-04-10

Django date template filter takes an argument python datetime object and converts to the specified format `(|date:'M d, Y')`

I guess, `widget.value` contains string `'2018-04-10'`, in this case, django date template filter will not work.
You can write your own template filter to convert string to python datetime object and then apply date - `(widget.value|own_filter|date:'M d, Y')`
or, the best solution, check the widget argument, it should be python datetime object.

P.S. You can little improve your code:

`{% if widget.value %} value="{{ widget.value|date:'M d, Y'}}"{% endif %}`